# aesm_service returned error: 1 in Gramine

Tags: sgx

when I want to run the sample code helloworld.py in gramine I get the error:

```
/gramine/CI-Examples/python$ gramine-sgx ./python scripts/helloworld.py
Gramine is starting. Parsing TOML manifest file, this may take some time...
error: aesm_service returned error: 1
error: load_enclave() failed with error -1
```

does any one know the reason, I have run progams with EGo before which uses attestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the remote attestation is not activated, so one way could be activation DCAP or using EPID attestation. If you wish to use EPID you can subscribe a spid and then :

```
make clean 
RA_CLIENT_SPID=12345678901234567890123456789012 RA_CLIENT_LINKABLE=0 make 
SGX=1
```

you have to use SPID which you have subscribed and based on the type of SPID set RA_CLIENT_LINKABLE=1 or RA_CLIENT_LINKABLE=0